# How to get cookies on internet explorer using Selenium webdriver - C#

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I need to run my test scripts on IE11. I am using c#.

Part of my script makes an API call using cookies on the current page.

I have this in my code:

```
IReadOnlyList<Cookie> cookies = _driver.Manage().Cookies.AllCookies;
```

to get cookies from current page.
It works well for Chrome, Firefox but for **IE11** it always returns 0. however, there are cookies on the page.

Answer (score 2):

There are too many open issues about this. But none of them is closed with the solution.
After several times I tried I decided to go with a workaround.

You can use JavaScript to get all cookies;

```
object cookies = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)_driver).ExecuteScript("return document.cookie");
```

**Edit:**

**32-Bit** Web Driver for Internet Explorer is working fine for cookies.
However it is not working with **64-Bit**.

You can use the latest version which you can download it from [here](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=3.141/);

```
IEDriverServer_Win32_3.141.5
```

Comment: This is a great answer! In fact I had already tried that before posting here and I was very hopeful when used this approach. However, it didn't help me what I wanted to do. The thing is document.cookie will only return non-HttpOnly Cookies. In my application (which is banking site), authentication token resides as a HttpOnly Cookie so it doesn't get returned by document.cookie. selenium's Cookie API is great and it does return all cookies for Chrome,Firefox etc but sadly not for IE11. They should really fix it.

Comment: What I ended up doing is, I start my test script on IE11 and then when i need to make an API call with authentication cookies, I do so using Chrome browser :-) then use that API response data to validate text nodes on IE11's DOM. sure, it is slower but i got no choice:-(

Comment: @DilipAgheda I can get the httponly cookies with the 32-Bit Internet Explorer driver. For example, could you please try Facebook website to get cookies? It is also sending cookies as httponly.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. I tried this but I resulted in lot of browser crashes while running the tests because I have windows 10 - 64 bit machine. that's why I had to use 64 bit driver which doesn't return httponly cookies. :-(